# jQuery multiple language script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Found this script on **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uUgWD/)** that would switch between languages. The problem is. When I type in the text with `<br>` it displays the breaks.

How can I get it to actually break the text?

Also, how can I get it to choose a default language? So every time you reload the page it will be that language that is selected. Otherwise, nothing is displayed until you select the language manually.

Also, I would highly appreciate it, if you can recommend other such scripts that are better then this one.

```
function getLanguageResources(){
    var fr = new Array(); var en = new Array();

    fr['settings'] = "paramètres"; en['settings'] = "settings";
    fr['default_feed'] = "Flux par défaut"; en['default_feed'] = "Default feed";
    fr['hidden'] = "Masquer"; en['hidden'] = " Hidden";
    fr['save_settings'] = "Enregistrer les paramètres"; en['save_settings'] = "Save settings";

    var resources = new Array();
    resources['fr'] = fr;
    resources['en'] = en;

    return resources;
}

function changeLanguage(lang){
    var langResources = getLanguageResources()[lang];

    $("span[name='lbl']").each(function(i, elt){
        $(elt).text(langResources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
    });    
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='radio-language']").click(function(){
        changeLanguage($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: To break the text, you need to apply the string as HTML instead of text, so in `changeLanguage()` you need to do `.html()` instead of `.text()`. To set a default language, set the `checked` attribute on the appropriate `input` element.

Comment: Why are you using `new Array()` when your variables contain objects? Arrays have numeric index, objects have string keys.

Comment: Also, your code would be easier to read if you used object literals instead of setting each property separately.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't write the code. Please write your suggestion in the answers section.

Comment: @univerio I added checked. The radio appears checked. But doesn't actually apply the value. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Boris It's not an answer to the question, it's an off-topic suggestion.

Comment: @Boris Call `changeLanguage()` with the default language after you set the `checked` attribute; or alternatively, if you don't want to repeat yourself, you can simulate a click on the radio button (which fires *all jQuery event handlers*): `.trigger("click")`.

Comment: @Barmar I'm pretty new to JavaScript, pretty sure you can tell. Would be very much interested in how it could be done. That why :)

Comment: @univerio Could you please answer that down below? I'm not sure I understand how to do it exactly...  Also, I tried using `<span class="">` and I got an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To break the text, apply your string as HTML instead of text:

```
$(elt).html(langResources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
```

To set a default language, set the `checked` attribute on the appropriate radio button and simulate a `click` event in your `$(document).ready` callback:

```
$("#radioEnglish").attr("checked", true).trigger("click");
```

Comment: Thank you that worked... One more thing. I tried adding span with class `en['sat'] = "<span class="">from 8:00am — to 7:00pm</span>";` and got an error. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Boris You need to escape your quotes inside your string. Otherwise JavaScript will parse it as two strings in a row: `<span class=` and `>from 8:00am — to 7:00pm</span>`. To escape a quote: `"this is \"quoted\" inside the string"`.

Comment: So like this? `<span class=\"bold\">`

Comment: But. It doesn't work. This is what I have: `en['fri'] = "Today, Friday open <br> <span class=\"bold\">from 8:00am — to 7:00pm</span>";`

Comment: @Boris Doesn't work? What did you want it to do? What did it do instead?

Comment: Yeah...I've applied `font-weight` onto that class. The text is not bold. For this specific thing. It's bold text. Later on I will be adding text with other styling. So It should pull the CSS from the class.

Comment: @Boris You'll need to post your CSS, or, even better, a jsfiddle that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Works great now! I overlooked something.

Comment: One more question for you...Is there anyway I can modify this scrip to accept all code possible. Without me having to make modifications to escape quotes? I just tried using some PHP, couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Boris That depends what "accept all code possible" means. You should probably make a separate question for that.